# Web service takes long time to run the first time

Tags: c#

I am new to writing and deploying web services and I have a web service that when I run it from my C# applications, it will take 4-8 seconds to respond the first call.  Subsequent calls are in the half second range.  If I call the web service from internet explorer, it returns immediately.

My Web service is a Soap web service running on windows web server 2008 server.  I have been looking for a solution for several days and nothing I have tried has helped.  The 2 things have tried that don't appear to work is precompile the XmlSerializers (Generate serialization assembly is on) and precompile the web service using aspnet_compiler.  The output of aspnet_compiler I copy to the server and paste into the appropriate folder.

My application is calling the web services by using the auto generated code web reference code created when you use the Add Web Reference wizard.

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: What do you mean by calling the web service from internet explorer?  What is your web service doing?

Comment: Is this WCF hosted in IIS? If so, you should add those tags.

Comment: I mean that I put the url for the web service into the browser which gives me a list of the methods I can run.  Then I select one of the methods that takes a string as an input and returns the string back.

Answer (score 2):

A common culprit is checking of Publisher Evidence (basically, assembly signatures) in the absense of open connectivity to the internet.

Try adding the following line to your ASPNET.CONFIG or APP.CONFIG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

See for background and details online articles, e.g.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfedev/archive/2008/11/26/best-practice-generatepublisherevidence-in-aspnet-config.aspx

Comment: I tried making the suggested changes to both files and I am still seeing the delay